# Scala Spark unit test hangs

Tags: apache-spark

Sorry to bother others. Our spark code works in prod but hangs in unit test. The way we test it is to mockito the java main class, sample code:

```
      mainInput = spy(
        new Input(
          // some initialization
        ))
      val spiedApp = spy(MainApp) // MainApp is the main class
      doReturn(args).when(spiedApp).getCliArgs // getCliArgs is one method of the class. Other methods are ommited.
      ....
      spiedApp.main(mainInput)
```

Our spark job reads S3 data, load as dataframe and run sql on it. It hangs somewhere. After I dump the thread according to https://medium.com/stepstone-tech/how-to-debug-freezing-junit-tests-e43c747a533a, I see something like:

```
    - locked <0x00000005c128d510> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    - locked <0x00000005c084d350> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    - locked <0x00000005c084dd38> (a io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySet)
    - locked <0x00000005c084dd50> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
.....
    - locked <0x00000005c1e47998> (a org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.BatchScanExec)
    - locked <0x00000005c19e97d8> (a org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution)
```

The stucking code is something like:

```
   spark.sql(s"select xx from xxx").dropDuplicates.collect
```

From the console, the stucked line is something like

```
[scalatest] 23/12/30 09:27:53 INFO V2ScanRelationPushDown: 
[scalatest] Output: _corrupt_record#30
```

Sorry I can not paste all source code. What I found

1. This seems not a known issue that udf could cause spark program hanging.
2. If I dump the process at different time, the output is same, not like anything is repeatedly computed.
3. I suspect it is some spark internal issue. If I run top, why is there only 1 java process? Is there a way to run spark test to at least start executor and driver process separately? Would that be something worthy trying?

The code change that caused this issue is that we removed a cache() call. So, in theory isEmpty and collect actions will trigger execution from beginning. That is likely the console output from V2ScanRelationPushDown. But even so it should be OK because it just reads the same input (test input) file again. We need to remove cache() otherwise our data is too big to hold in memory. Our computation cost is low.

From console log, if we added cache, we see:

```
[scalatest] 23/12/30 11:02:25 INFO V2ScanRelationPushDown: 
[scalatest] Output: _corrupt_record#30, type#31, metadata#32, timestamp#33, sequence#34L, data#35
[scalatest]          
[scalatest] 23/12/30 11:02:25 INFO V2ScanRelationPushDown: 
[scalatest] Output: _corrupt_record#30, type#31, metadata#32, timestamp#33, sequence#34L, data#35
```

After we removed cache, we see below (and it hangs):

```
[scalatest] 23/12/30 11:02:25 INFO V2ScanRelationPushDown: 
[scalatest] Output: _corrupt_record#30, type#31, metadata#32, timestamp#33, sequence#34L, data#35
[scalatest]          
[scalatest] 23/12/30 11:02:25 INFO V2ScanRelationPushDown: 
[scalatest] Output:
```

Our actual code to read data (before spark.sql) is:

```
spark.read.format(format).options(options.get).schema(schema.get).load(prefixesToRead: _*)
```

We used some pushdown filter. That means we revised the logic of FilePartitionReaderFactory, TextBasedFileScan, FileScanBuilder, etc. Our logic greps the input file before putting it to spark memory.

Can someone tells me what is the relationship from spark.read to V2ScanRelationPushDown? Earlier I said execution will be triggered twice, but from our log, at least our implementation of FilePartitionReaderFactory is not triggered for the 2nd time. However, by comparing the logs above for V2ScanRelationPushDown before and after code change, it seems to me reading data files has issue without cache().

Thanks.